# Return loop getElementsByClassName not work

Tags: javascript

*is a public question discussed in various communities*
I have not gotten the return of a simple loop works like this:

[see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55b3w4xq/3/)

```
function className(cls){
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
   for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) { 
     a = divs[i]
   }
    return a;
}
//example use
className('source').style.display='block';
```

**is important to use native javascript**

Comment: there's no question here...!? (BTW, this will always return `undefined`. what's the point?)

Comment: It simply doesn't work like that, you're overwriting the `a` variable on every iteration of the loop, and you can only set styles on one element at a time, so you have to set the styles **inside the loop**

Comment: That's just not going to work. You can however write a function that allows you to set one or more CSS properties on elements selected by class name.

Comment: the important thing is to get a return like jquery

Comment: @avrilalejandro meaning what? jQuery is a JavaScript library. Are you trying to... return a JavaScript library, or what?

Comment: @avrilalejandro please write proper English. I cannot even make sense of your last comment.

Comment: People. No imagination. Avril wants wants to use plain js to set properties on all elements returned by a function. Like jQuery $(".someclass").dosomethingtoallelements()

Comment: significant response @ mplungjan . I am looking for the solution ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go the whole hog and extend the HTMLcollection prototype:

```
function className(cls){
    return document.getElementsByClassName(cls);//a HTMLCollection
}
//extend the HTMLCollection prototype
HTMLCollection.prototype.style = function(newStyles) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        for (var key in newStyles) {
          if (newStyles.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              this[i].style[key] = newStyles[key];
          }
        }
    }
    return this;
};

//example use
className('source').style({display:'block', color:'red'});
```

Not necessarily something I'd recommend but [here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/55b3w4xq/8/)

Answer (score 1):

don't know if this is what you are looking for, but if you are trying to change css properties of elements :

```
function changeClassName(name, attr, value) {

  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('source');

  for(var x = 0; x < divs.length; x++){

    divs[x].style[attr] = value;
  }

};

changeClassName('source','display','block');

//or
changeClassName('source','display','block');
```